# Please Delete This Account

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I am really really sorry to post this on main, but apparently there's a minimum rep necessary to post on meta --- and there's no easily available info on how to contact the moderators.

I have hit the "delete" button a gazillion times, but this account (created very recently) will not go away, and its existence seems to prevent me from logging into my usual account.  When I attempt to log into that account, I get logged into this one instead.

The help pages tell me to hit the delete button.  That doesn't work.

I have tried the "recover account" link sent me by email, etc, but no matter what I do, I end up logged into this account instead of my usual.   I have tried disabling cookies, but then I can't log in at all.  As soon as I allow the cookies again, I'm suddenly automatically logged back into this account.  Since the original cookies were erased, I can't figure out what's making stackexchange think it knows who I am, but it's extremely persistent.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try asking the SE team for help: http://math.stackexchange.com/contact/other

Comment: Also, I think we should keep upvoting this question, for no reason at all. It's at 11 now, gaining a few votes since the user was deleted. Let's get to a Good Question at least.

Comment: whatever you wrote make you laugh, @40votes - except for your answers to math questions, of course.

Answer (score 28):

**Feel my lightning!**  ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You have ThunderGod superpowers now?

Comment: *There can be only one!*

Comment: Only one moderator? Doesn't seem to be a good idea ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could also have flagged a post by this user or your real one as

> it needs ♦ moderator attention
>   -> other

and asked a moderator to delete your account. However, it is often better to [merge your accounts](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact/user-merge) - the latter is useful if you accidentally created a new account but want posts made by that migrated to your "real" one.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has something to do with your browser, namely, Chrome. So I guess what you encounter is that you are trying to log-in one of your accounts via, say, Google, but Chrome logged you in automatically without allowing you to choose.

To my experience, any browser, except for Chrome, will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy to solve, just erase your cookies, not only disable them ;)